# "Some index files failed to download" while installing the Spotify client

Tags: apt

after updating from 13.10 to 14.04 from LiveCD my Spotify installation dissapeared.

I tried to install it as before by following Spotify guide and entering these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" &&
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59 &&
sudo apt-get update -qq &&
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

but all I get is this error:

```
dominic@dominic-MS-7592:~$ sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" &&
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59 &&
> sudo apt-get update -qq &&
> sudo apt-get install spotify-client
[sudo] password for dominic: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.DQvohEce8A --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
gpg: requesting key 94558F59 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 94558F59: "Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <operations@spotify.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/trusty/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 54.230.231.43 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/trusty/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 54.230.231.43 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
dominic@dominic-MS-7592:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

You need edit the sourcelist file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list
```

Comment the Spotify line:

```
## Spotify
#deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

And add this line:

```
deb http://repository-origin.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Save and exit

Update&&Upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Link: http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-11-for-GNU-Linux/td-p/842969/page/2

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Spotify server is broken at this moment. The packages for Spotify are in repository.spotify.com/dists/stable, not in repository.spotify/dists/trusty. That is why apt-get can't find them. I have Spotify running happily, but when I do a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall spotify-client` I get the same 404 errors.
As of this moment, the URL http://repository.spotify.com/dists redirects to http://repository-origin.spotify.com/dists, which to me suggests that someone over at Spotify is busy moving things around.
Currently, I can't even find any .deb files to manually download.

Comment: thanks for the info. ill try downloading again later and maybe then I'll succeed

Comment: Now I got this error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7742626/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exact error messages. I am running 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04. What worked for me was to update the public key for spotify-client:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
```

Then `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`

The `--fix-missing` may be redundant or unnecessary, but `apt-get` suggested it while I was doing many updates to my computer.

I'm not an expert on the matter, but it worked.  I thought it was an issue with updating the spotify package itself, but it turned out I already had the most updated version.

In your case, with a fresh install, and possibly loosing the spotify package (or whatever happened), I would suggest what [elgastelum](https://askubuntu.com/users/297875/elgastelum) advised, and update the sourcelist file before reinstalling or updating:

```
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

I hope my advice isn't confusing or 'off the mark'. I don't know everything but what I do know I try to share. Cheers and good luck!